# Was time dilated in the early universe?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation, observable-universe

If energy is responsible for most of our mass, and mass is responsible for the effects on spacetime, then in the very early universe when its mass energy density was enormous, one second in time to a *hypothetical* outside observer, if one outside the universe could exist and experience a sense of time, would be billions of years to any creatures within the universe. Is this not true? In that case how old is the universe to such a *hypothetical* observer?

Comment: I asked a similar question over on the Astronomy SE community (https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11050/age-of-the-universe-vs-its-contents), which is where this question ought to be, IMHO.

Comment: I believe your question is not about an *outside* observer, but about the time dilation in the early universe. To avoid this confusion, I have edited the question. If this is not what you meant, please reverse the edits or let me know and I would.

Comment: My question is related to time dilation in general relativity.

Answer (score 1):

There is no age of the universe "from outside". Time and space exist only "inside the universe". Therefore you can only determine the age of the universe inside the universe.

Comment: How do you know there is no time outside our universe? It may be different than what we have. A computer has an oscillating  crystal that keeps its time. We may have something similar, ruled by the laws of relativity. You just don’t know. But suppose it did? Now calculate the age of the Universe from such an observer.

Comment: @user44949 - The universe  is by definition "all of space and time and its contents" (wikipedia). Therefore, your "hypothetical outside observer" cannot exist. He would be part of the content of all of space and time, which obviously is a logical contradiction. A similar question is, "what was before the beginning of the universe (big bang)?", which has  been compared to the question "what is north of the north pole?"

Comment: Suppose a computer simulated the Big Bang? That would be outside the space times fabric of that simulated universe.